# If $x,y,z$ are three mutually independent variables then is $x^2$ and $yz$ pairwise independent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x,y,z$ are three mutually independent variables then is $x^2$ and $yz$ pairwise independent?

How can I tackle it? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint : consider the case $z=\frac{x^2}{y}$. Do you assume anything on the distribution of $x,y,z$ ?

Comment: Actually @Ewan can you please make it clear to me what does the question say?

Comment: So you don't even understand the question ? Then I'm afraid we can't help you much here on MSE. Is it homework ?

Comment: I would re-phrase the question as, "you chose an $x$ such that $x^2$ equals a certain value: does this impose any constraints on the value that can be taken by $yz$?"

Answer (score 1):

Hint: just use the simple, formal definition of independence. Two random variables $a$ and $b$ are independent if, for every $A$ and $B$,

$P[a=A, b=B]=P[a=A]\cdot P[b=B]$.

i.e. the probability that $a$ and $b$ are simultaneously equal to, respectively, $A$ and $B$ coincides with the product of the probability that $a$ equals to $A$ (averaged over all possible outcomes of $b$), and the probability that $b$ equals $B$ (averaged over all possible outcomes of $a$).

Comment: In a vector space of all polynomials of degree $2$ in $x,y,z$ are $x^2$ and $yz$ independent?